# docker compose inside docker causes error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working in a task where I am having to use docker compose inside a docker container. When I perform `docker compose --file setup.yaml`, I get the following error.

> no valid drivers found: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Is there a way to resolve this error?

What I have tried:
I looked at a few documentation on the internet and I am performing a volume mount of the path to socket daemon as follows,

```
 docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it -d <container_id>
```

But after this command, the container exits after a while. Not sure if the approach is correct.

Comment: is your docker really running?

Comment: The command you show is the correct approach. As I read your post, your error message isn't from running that command but from running another command?

Comment: its from running docker compose --file setup.yaml from inside the container

Comment: I ran docker command inside the container and saw that docker is not running inside the container although installed.Is there a way to start it inside the container.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want a container in a container or to control your host from within a container? Do you realise that the -it flag makes the container interactive and it exits as soon as you close the shell?